# nginx favicon versioning

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

My first nginx server is running the Anguar website with PNG images perfectly as `www.abc1.com/first/favicon.ico?v=1`, but my another nginx server running the `www.abc2.com/first/favicon.ico?v=1` is giving the error of `Page not found`. Both servers are using the same code.

**This one is working fine.**

[image: This one is running fine]
[image: This one is running fine]

and the nginx `/var/logs` are giving the error

> "GET /first/favicon.ico?v=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 550 "https://www.abc1.com/first/favicon.ico?v=1"

**This one is not working.**

[image: This one is having error]
[image: This one is having error]

and the nginx `/var/logs` are giving the error

> "GET /first/favicon.ico?v=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://www.abc2.com/first/favicon.ico?v=1"

**I am Currently using these headers in Nginx.conf.**

```
 include block_http_methods.in;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers''authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,deptid,srvid';
```

Comment: what you have in your logs ? Did you check with the absolute url/link to the favicon on the server where you have an error ? Did you tried to get the favicon with curl directly from the server ?

Comment: Yes I checked it with Curl -I .

Comment: Please check the latest images in same post , above.

Comment: I show `Content-Type: text/html` on the second screenhost. Maybe check your configuration, your php routing, filename, syntax....

Comment: HTTP status 304 "not modified" is not an error, it means that there is no need to retransmit the requested resources. It is an implicit redirection to a cached resource.

Comment: yes , I also shared the nginx logs, please check and revert.

Comment: So can you please  tell me what should I add in Nginx Configuration to get Rid of this error. I also Added the Nginx Configuration in this same post.